# How to show a specific gateway in Shopify checkout page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

Does anyone know how to show a specific gateway if a customer spends over a certain amount.
Is it possible in Shopify? my store is shopify plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If store is shopify plus, you should use `Script Editor` app. you can customize and add featured functions for `line item`,  `shipping`, `payment` and `discount`

you'd be able to find your answer!
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/payment-gateway-scripts#show-gateways-by-spend